# How to match nodes in Cypher query based on different directions per relationship type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a graph with two types of relationships: `Sync` and `Async`.

I want a query to give me a subgraph, meaning all the nodes that can be reached directly or indirectly.

This query works for this:

```
MATCH (s {type: 'service')
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:Async|Sync*]->(dependent)
WITH s, COLLECT(DISTINCT dependent) AS allDependentNodes
```

This gives me every node that can be reached via an Sync or Async relationship.

But now I'd like to use a different direction based on the type of relation. I want nodes that can be reached via outgoing Sync `a -> b` OR reached via incoming Async `a <- b`.

So it's like an OR'd match condition. I've tried a few things without much success:

```
MATCH (s {type: 'service')
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:Sync*]->(dependent), (s)<-[:Async*]-(d)
WITH s, totalNodes, COLLECT(DISTINCT dependent) AS allDependentNodes
```

How can I OR'd together relationship matches or how can I match different types of relationships with different directions?

Comment: Removing the direction means it is bi-directional.

Comment: @jose_bacoy thanks! I don't want them to be bi-directional tho. I want Sync to go into one direction only, and Async into the other direction only

Comment: you can use UNION to collect these two: sync->b | async <-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow all paths composed of relationships with either type `Sync` and direction outbound, or type `Async` and direction inbound, the following [quantified path pattern](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/concepts/#quantified-path-patterns) will work:

```sql
MATCH (s {type: 'service'}) 
        ((n)-[r]-() WHERE (n = startNode(r) AND r:Sync) 
          OR (n = endNode(r) AND r:Async))+ (dependent)
RETURN s, collect(DISTINCT dependent) AS allDependentNodes
```

Comment: Nice! Gonna try this out. Just to confirm, would this allow for a mix of relation types? E.g. `A -[Sync]-> B <-[Async]- C` or just `A-Sync->B-Sync->C` and `A<-[Async]-B<-[Async]-C`

Comment: All relationships on each path would be the same. Is that what you were after?

Comment: No, within a path Sync or Async should be allowed. It's just that the direction would be different depending on the relationship type. But a path should be able to contain both types

Comment: OK updated it with a different approach that fits your definition.